libgpiod C++ 2.1.x error reading GPIO line
Based on the libgpiod github example, I've made a simple C++ class to listen for multiple lines, as follows:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <gpiod.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

#include "gpiod.hpp"

#define GPIO_PORT_1_LINE 0
#define GPIO_PORT_2_LINE 1
#define GPIO_PORT_3_LINE 5
#define GPIO_PORT_4_LINE 6

#define GPIO_CHIP_NAME "/dev/gpiochip0"

IO::IO()
{
    std::cout << "IO constructor" << std::endl;
}

IO::~IO()
{
    std::cout << "IO destructor" << std::endl;
}

void IO::loop()
{
    std::cout << "Loop start" << std::endl;

    const std::vector<int> offsets = {
         GPIO_PORT_1_LINE,
         GPIO_PORT_2_LINE,
         GPIO_PORT_3_LINE,
         GPIO_PORT_4_LINE };

    try
    {
        // Open chip
        std::filesystem::path chip_path(GPIO_CHIP_NAME);

        std::cout << "STEP 1" << std::endl;

        // Get the requested lines
        gpiod::line::offsets line_offsets;

        for (int offset : offsets)
            line_offsets.push_back(offset);

        std::cout << "STEP 2" << std::endl;

        auto chip = gpiod::chip(chip_path);

        std::cout << "STEP 3" << std::endl;

        // Prepare que line request
        auto request_builder = chip.prepare_request();

        std::cout << "STEP 4" << std::endl;

        // Set the consumer
        request_builder.set_consumer("io_test");

        std::cout << "STEP 5" << std::endl;

        // Create the line settings
        gpiod::line_settings line_settings;
        line_settings.set_direction(gpiod::line::direction::INPUT);
        line_settings.set_edge_detection(gpiod::line::edge::BOTH);

        std::cout << "STEP 6" << std::endl;

        // Add the line settings
        request_builder.add_line_settings(line_offsets, line_settings);

        std::cout << "STEP 7" << std::endl;

        // Request the line
        auto request = request_builder.do_request();

        std::cout << "STEP0 8" << std::endl;

        gpiod::edge_event_buffer buffer;

        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << "BLOCK WAIT" << std::endl;

            /* Blocks until at leat one event available */
            request.read_edge_events(buffer);
            std::cout << "LINE READ" << std::endl;

            for (const auto &event : buffer)
            {
                std::cout << "IO EVENT" << std::endl;

                std::cout << "offset: " << event.line_offset()
                          << "  event #" << event.global_seqno()
                          << "  line event #" << event.line_seqno()
                          << "  timestamp " << event.timestamp_ns().ns()
                          << ::std::endl;

                auto type = event.type();
                auto ns = std::chrono::nanoseconds(event.timestamp_ns().ns());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

When running I'm getting the following error:
IO Constructor
Loop start
STEP 1
STEP 2
STEP 3
STEP 4
STEP 5
STEP 6
STEP 7
Error: error requesting GPIO lines: Device or resource busy

I have tried gpiomon and it can access the lines and get data changes. Haven't found anyone else using the line - rebooted - ant the same behaviour.
What can be causing the problem? Is the function calls in the right order? Am I missing some call?

First let me express I simply use the gpiio_v2 ioctl kernel interface, so I don't have direct experience with libgpiod built to use that interface. The reason being is libgpiod implements every aspect of the kernel user-interface which leads to significant complexity. Looking at step 7 and 8, what I'm unclear on is your use of the enum for offsets. The line offsets are a bitmap indicating the line-by-bit-index you wish to utilize. I'd double check the library documentation on that point to make sure the bitmaps of 9 - 3 you use do what you want.

Also, double check /dev/gpiochip0 is owned by root:gpio and that you are a member of the gpio group. That can cause access problems. The pinctrl package and raspi-gpio are handy command-line tools to look at all gpio pins (as well as manipulate them from the command line for testing purposes, etc.)

@DavidC.Rankin  One of the functions of libgpiod, over the raw kernel uAPI, is to provide a simplified interface so the user can directly use offsets rather than have to deal with bitmaps etc.  Perhaps YOU should double check the library documentation or restrict your comments to the interface you are familiar with?  And not having access to the gpiochip does not generate the EBUSY that the OP is seeing - it would generate an EPERM at Step 2.

What is io_gpioint_t?  As I can't find that type I replaced it with int and that works for me (using your loop function a the main() on a Pi4)...  STEP 7 STEP0 8 BLOCK WAIT

Mistyped... gpioint_t.... Is there a way to find out who is locking the gpiochio0? Still same problem here... I'm using a Toradex module...

The gpioinfo command line tool reports the info for all lines, including if they are requested and by what consumer.

Try to inspect the status of the GPIO lines by using the gpiod tool gpiodetect or gpioinfo gpiochip0. If any of the lines are in use by another application or marked as reserved, this could explain the issue.
